# Ipad xcode plist problem

Tags: xcode, ipad, plist, bundle, identifier

I'm having a problem with my plist file. Maybe you will be able to figure out the solution.

I made a project for ipad, everything is working well on the ipad simulator, absolutely no problem.
Now I decided to test it on an ipad device. Therefore I modified the "Bundle Identifier" in the plist which was by default "com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}" and put "com.mycompanysname.applicationID". Oh, I forgot to mention that I've already created an application ID for that project.
Now here comes the problem, as soon as the "Bundle identifier" has been modified, the project's no longer runs neither on the simulator nor on the device. What I mean by it no longer runs is that the project when launched, a black screen appears but nothing else.

I decided to debug it with break points, it's somehow very strange as the app doesn't even reach the "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method in the delegate.

The project no longer runs on the simulator even if i put back the Bundle identifier back what was written in it by default. Thus unusable.

Maybe someone has already come across this problem, your help is needed guys.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the product name in the target build settings under the "Product Name" key. That is used in more than one location in the app and they all have to sync.